# coxph() X matrix deemed to be singular;

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression

I'm having some trouble using coxph(). I've two categorical variables:"tecnologia" and "pais", and I want to evaluate the possible interaction effect of "pais" on "tecnologia"."tecnologia" is a variable factor with 2 levels: gps and convencional. And "pais" as 2 levels: PT and ES. I have no idea why this warning keeps appearing. 
Here's the code and the output:

```
cox_AC<-coxph(Surv(dados_temp$dias_seg,dados_temp$status)~tecnologia*pais,data=dados_temp)
Warning message:
In coxph(Surv(dados_temp$dias_seg, dados_temp$status) ~ tecnologia *  :
  X matrix deemed to be singular; variable 3

> cox_AC
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(dados_temp$dias_seg, dados_temp$status) ~ 
    tecnologia * pais, data = dados_temp)


                       coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z     p
tecnologiagps        -0.152     0.859    0.400 -0.38 7e-01
paisPT                1.469     4.345    0.406  3.62 3e-04
tecnologiagps:paisPT     NA        NA    0.000    NA    NA

Likelihood ratio test=23.8  on 2 df, p=6.82e-06  n= 127, number of events= 64
```

I'm opening another question about this subject, although I made a similar one some months ago, because I'm facing the same problem again, with other data. And this time I'm sure it's not a data related problem.

Can somebody help me?
Thank you

**UPDATE:**
The problem does not seem to be a perfect classification

```
> xtabs(~status+tecnologia,data=dados)  

      tecnologia
status conv doppler gps  
     0   39       6  24  
     1   30       3  34 

> xtabs(~status+pais,data=dados)  

      pais  
status ES PT  
     0 71  8  
     1 49 28  
 > xtabs(~tecnologia+pais,data=dados)

          pais  
tecnologia ES PT
   conv    69  0
   doppler  1  8
   gps     30 28
```

Comment: This looks like 'perfect classification' (i.e. when looking at the interaction, for at least one combination of factors *all* observations have a certain status). Have you looked at cross-tables of `status` by the variables and their interaction?

Comment: What do you mean? I don't understand what I've to look for..

Comment: 1. what is the result of: `xtabs(~tecnologica+pais,data=dados)` ? 2. Why not `dput` you data and let people check it out rather than speculate?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a simple example which seems to reproduce your problem:

```
> library(survival)
> (df1 <- data.frame(t1=seq(1:6),
                    s1=rep(c(0, 1), 3),
                    te1=c(rep(0, 3), rep(1, 3)),
                    pa1=c(0,0,1,0,0,0)
                    ))
   t1 s1 te1 pa1
 1  1  0   0   0
 2  2  1   0   0
 3  3  0   0   1
 4  4  1   1   0
 5  5  0   1   0
 6  6  1   1   0

> (coxph(Surv(t1, s1) ~ te1*pa1, data=df1))
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(t1, s1) ~ te1 * pa1, data = df1)


        coef exp(coef) se(coef)         z  p
te1      -23  9.84e-11    58208 -0.000396  1
pa1      -23  9.84e-11   100819 -0.000229  1
te1:pa1   NA        NA        0        NA NA
```

Now lets look for 'perfect classification' like so:

```
> (xtabs( ~ s1+te1, data=df1))
   te1
s1  0 1
  0 2 1
  1 1 2
> (xtabs( ~ s1+pa1, data=df1))
   pa1
s1  0 1
  0 2 1
  1 3 0
```

Note that a value of `1` for `pa1` *exactly* predicts having a status `s1` equal to `0`. That is to say, based on your data, if you know that `pa1==1` then you can be sure than `s1==0`. Thus fitting Cox's model is not appropriate in this setting and will result in numerical errors.
This can be seen with

```
> coxph(Surv(t1, s1) ~ pa1, data=df1)
```

giving

```
Warning message:
In fitter(X, Y, strats, offset, init, control, weights = weights,  :
  Loglik converged before variable  1 ; beta may be infinite.
```

It's important to look at these cross tables before fitting models. Also it's worth starting with simpler models before considering those involving interactions.

If we add the interaction term to `df1` manually like this:

```
> (df1 <- within(df1,
+               te1pa1 <- te1*pa1))
  t1 s1 te1 pa1 te1pa1
1  1  0   0   0      0
2  2  1   0   0      0
3  3  0   0   1      0
4  4  1   1   0      0
5  5  0   1   0      0
6  6  1   1   0      0
```

Then check it with

```
> (xtabs( ~ s1+te1pa1, data=df1))
   te1pa1
s1  0
  0 3
  1 3
```

We can see that it's a *useless* classifier, i.e. it does not help predict status `s1`.

When combining all 3 terms, the fitter does manage to produce a numerical value for `te1` and `pe1` even though `pe1` is a perfect predictor as above. However a look at the values for the coefficients and their errors shows them to be implausible.

**Edit** @JMarcelino: If you look at the warning message from the first `coxph` model in the example, you'll see the warning message:

```
2: In coxph(Surv(t1, s1) ~ te1 * pa1, data = df1) :
  X matrix deemed to be singular; variable 3
```

Which is likely the same error you're getting and is due to this problem of classification. Also, your third cross table `xtabs(~ tecnologia+pais, data=dados)` is not as important as the table of `status` by `interaction term`. You could add the interaction term manually first as in the example above then check the cross table. Or you could say:

```
> with(df1,
       table(s1, pa1te1=pa1*te1))
   pa1te1
s1  0
  0 3
  1 3
```

That said, I notice one of the cells in your third table has a zero (`conv`, `PT`) meaning you have no observations with this combination of predictors. This is going to cause problems when trying to fit.

In general, the outcome should be have *some* values for all levels of the predictors and the predictors should not classify the outcome as exactly *all or nothing* or *50/50*.

**Edit 2** @user75782131 Yes, generally speaking `xtabs` or a similar cross-table should be performed in models where the outcome and predictors are discrete i.e. have a limited no. of levels. If 'perfect classification' is present then a predictive model / regression may not be appropriate. This is true for example for logistic regression (outcome is binary) as well as Cox's model.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation, now I know what is a 'perfect classification'. The problem seems to be soved, now I only get the warning: "X matrix deemed to be singular", that's why I changed the title of the question. Could this be due to high correlation?

Comment: @dardisco, if I understand it correctly, `xtabs` can be used to determine which covariates that can be included in the formula `coxph()`?